# How do I disable Do Not Disturb While Driving in iOS 11 if I'm a passenger?

Tags: ios, focus

Do Not Disturb While Driving in iOS 11 looks like a helpful feature unless I'm a passenger. How do I disable it if I'm an passenger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 3D Touch device, 3D Touch the notification on the lock screen and choose the "I'm not driving" option.

If you have a non-3D Touch device, you will need to long-press the notification and then choose the "I'm not driving" option.

Comment: I was hoping you had to pull the parking break or convince Siri you weren’t a chat bot.